# Failed to parse the WFS response when the srsName property contains more info beside the projection

Tags: openlayers-3

It works with:

```
<kms:geometri>
    <gml:LineString srsName="EPSG:25832">
      <gml:coordinates>718883.722,6193416.066 718847.441,6193419.519</gml:coordinates>
    </gml:LineString>
  </kms:geometri>
</kms:MatrikelSkel>
```

BUT not with:

```
<kms:geometri>
        <gml:LineString srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832">
          <gml:coordinates>718883.722,6193416.066 718847.441,6193419.519</gml:coordinates>
        </gml:LineString>
      </kms:geometri>
    </kms:MatrikelSkel>
```

The reason I guess is srcName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to register an equivalent projection (make sure you have defined EPSG:25832 before) for example:

```
ol.proj.addEquivalentProjections([ol.proj.get(‘EPSG:25832'), new ol.proj.Projection({code: 'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:25832'})])
```

Comment: Great! It works like a charm and thank you so much. Just a comment that why we do not make OL3 working like OL2 where we do not need to add the equivalent projections :-)

Comment: Actually the old behaviour was part of proj4js, but this was taken out of the new proj4js version.